# Disable image load in Chrome with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, image, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

How to Disable The load of images in chrome

```
browser.get("chrome://settings/content/images")
time.sleep(5)
images = browser.find_element_by_id('addSite')
images.click()
text = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[id='input']")
text.send_keys("https://www.instagram.com/")
accept = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Añadir']")
accept.click()
```

i was trying to go to the settings page in chrome and click in blocked sites and add instagram, so it will block the images in instagram, but it cant find the buttons on the page.
Anyone knows another way?
i tried to use an extension but its .crx and chrome only likes .crx3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
```